# NestJs not reading environmental variables

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, nestjs, dotenv

I followed the the Nest [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) to create the config but it's not working

**app.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot(config),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    MailModule,
    CloudinaryModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

`.env` file is on the src folder

**mail.module.ts**

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
          user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
          pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
```

But when I run the app its undefined my key value pairs are also there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is ConfigModule's env variables are only available at run time but not on the nestjs initial state.

To allow getting the .env after nestjs initialised, you can use async config to in MailerModule.

**mail.config.ts**

```js
export class MailerConfig implements MailerOptionsFactory {
  createMailerOptions(): MailerOptions | Promise<MailerOptions> {
    console.log(process.env.MAIL_USER); // should have value
    return {
      transport: {
        service: 'Gmail',
        auth: {
          user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
          pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS,
        },
      },
    };
  }
}
```

**mail.module.ts**

```js
console.log(process.env.MAIL_USER); // undefined
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: MailerConfig,
    }),
  ],
})
export class MailModule {}
```

---

you can use `useFactory` as well without the need of class, here I want to console.log the .env for you to check with so i used config class.