# ConfigModule isn't working properly in nestjs

Tags: mongodb, nestjs

I am working on nestjs and mongoose recently. I put my MongoDB connection links on .env file. I have configured my nestjs application using ConfigModule. I followed the nestjs [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration). But I have no idea why env variables are not working for me.

I have one extra module.ts file called **content.module.ts** in which I am connecting to mongodb. I have configured this ConfigModule in my **app.module.ts** and put it as global.

```
// app.module.ts

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: './config/.env',
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    ContentModule, //another module
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
// content.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.CONTENT_DB_CONNECTION_STRING),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'App', schema: AppSchema },]),
  ],
})
export class ContentModule {}
```

When I run my project using the debugger, I found that MongooseModule was first getting executed in the content.module.ts file, and then configModule was getting executed.

I even tried to configure the configModule in the content.module.ts file itself like below but no luck.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '../../config/.env',
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.CONTENT_DB_CONNECTION_STRING),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'App', schema: AppSchema },]),
  ],
})
export class ContentModule {}
```

```
.env file

PORT=3000
CONTENT_DB_CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://localhost:27017/content
```

[project structure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NOFrGuXhtmn65FW9-Avu9IONZQFUJkOj/view?usp=sharing)

I didn't get why mongoose dependencies are getting executed before the nestjs dependencies? And I also need help to fix this env variable.

Comment: Can this SO answer you?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67483932/15569492

Comment: Your ConfigModule.forRoot is performing an i/o process (loading the .env) which your MongooseModule is a dependency of, but its not clear that it is. So everything is getting loaded at once. Try using a factory provider method to [configure your mongoose module, injecting the configservice](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#connection).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671358/10847871 I have explained this in detail over here.